# Whats the difference between list and array?

Tags: c++

Wants the difference between a list and an array. I know how to use both, but I don't the difference. I tried searching everywhere on every website, but I still couldn't find a reasonable website.

Comment: link? Did you mean list?

Comment: If you knew how to use both then you'd know what the difference was. And if you'd searched even on one website, you'd know the answer to this. Keep researching. You'll find it.

Comment: "I tried searching everywhere" - There are even detailed explanations on Wikipedia, with a lot of good references.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/
you might use that
array is different from list!(you said that though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`list` reference in cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/):

> Compared to other base standard sequence containers (array, vector and
>   deque), lists perform generally better in inserting, extracting and
>   moving elements in any position within the container for which an
>   iterator has already been obtained, and therefore also in algorithms
>   that make intensive use of these, like sorting algorithms.

Hope this helps.